# Where to find the parking coordinates of the aircraft in the Apron?

Tags: airport, aeronautical-charts, airport-design, chart-supplement, aeronautical-information

Is it possible to find out the coordinates of where the aircraft park in an the Apron? I mean some sort of list for each terminal or aeronautical chart.
I was thinking about the AIP (Aeronautical Information Publication) but i could not find it.

Comment: Which airport in particular?

Comment: A point to note is that the AIP airport chart as well as Jeppessen and other charts have a Lat/Long grid marked in Degrees and Minutes with notches every 10th of a Minute. Jepps actually have only notches marked on the edge of the diagram. It's good to also know that 1 minute of Latitude = 1 Nautical Mile (But not Longitude). FMC's need an accuracy of tenths of a degree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The airport charts usually contain the coordinates of all parking positions. The charts that are available from the FAA AIP (e.g. [here for JFK](https://nfdc.faa.gov/nfdcApps/services/ajv5/airportDisplay.jsp?airportId=JFK)) only contain a single ground chart with the airport diagram:

[image: KFJK airport diagram]

These do not include the coordinates. But my Jeppesen charts contain coordinates for all parking positions. E.g. some gates at JFK:

[image: Coordinates]

They can either be found in dedicated charts for airports with many gates (like JFK shown above), or they are included on the airport overview chart for smaller airports with fewer gates.

Aircraft navigation databases also typically include the positions, so the Inertial Navigation can be initialized with a position based on airport code and parking position.

As far as I know, there is no free resource that would list the coordinates though.

Comment: Perfect exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot

Comment: ... or [this one](https://www.aurora.nats.co.uk/htmlAIP/Publications/2020-01-30-AIRAC/graphics/27157.pdf) for EGLC (London City) from [NATS UK](http://www.nats-uk.ead-it.com/public/index.php%3Foption=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=1&Itemid=2.html). For Germany, for instance, such information is not available for free.